# How to handle optional fields in JSON parsing in play 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using the new Play 2.1-RC1 framework and I have a class that has an Option[] field, something like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.util._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._
import play.api.libs.json.Format._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Test(name: String, value: Option[String])

object Test {
  implicit val testFormat = (
    (__ \ "name").format[String] and
    (__ \ "value").format[Option[String]] 
  )(Test.apply, unlift(Test.unapply))
  def fromJson(js: String): Test = {
    Json.fromJson[Test](Json.parse(js)).fold(
        valid   = { t => t},
        invalid = { e => {
          val missingField = (e(0)._1).toString.substring(1)
          val badJs = js.trim
          val newJs = badJs.substring(0, badJs.length()-1)+",\""+missingField+"\":null}"
          fromJson(newJs)
        }} 
    )
  }
}
```

I want to be able to handle JSON strings that omit the optional "value" data, e.g.

```
val y = """{"name":"someone"}"""
```

(edited question)
I can rewrite the json string (rather clumsily) as shown in the validation step, but 
is there a simpler pattern I can use to supply None for missing Optional fields? Note that this rewrite does not work with nested structures, or anywhere where I can't simply append the missing field.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Test(name: String, value: Option[String])

implicit val testFormat = Json.format[Test]

def hoge = Action(Json.parse.json) { request => 
    Json.fromJson[Test](request.body)
    ...
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that the json isn't coming from the request but from a websocket.

Comment: @NickStoughton `Iteratee.foreach[JsValue](event => Json.fromJson[Test](event))`

Comment: @NickStoughton JFYI https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/websocket-chat/app/models/ChatRoom.scala

Comment: Thanks! that helps! But there's still a problem if the incoming JSON is missing fields that the formatter (reader) expects. I've updated the example above to show one workaround.

Answer (score 6):

OK ... so the answer is very simple. Use

```
fomatOpt()
```

for optional fields. So the test formatter now looks like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.util._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._
import play.api.libs.json.Format._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Test(name: String, value: Option[String])

object Test {
  implicit val testFormat = (
    (__ \ "name").format[String] and
    (__ \ "value").formatOpt[String] 
  )(Test.apply, unlift(Test.unapply))

  def fromJson(js: String): Test = {
    Json.fromJson[Test](Json.parse(js)).fold(
      valid   = { t => t},
      invalid = { e => {
        println("BAD JSON!")
        null
      }} 
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the case when using scala macros for injecting Reads/Writes/Format? For example in your case we can write just
`implicit val testFormat = Json.format[Test]`
How can you manage optional JSON values in that case?