# Convert json array to Seq of model class in Scala Play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Scala Play framework and [Instagram API](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/), and I want to extract a json array to my model class `User`:

`case class User(val userId: String, val username: String, val profilePhoto: String, val name: String)`

An json array example from the API is something like this:

```
{
  "pagination":  {},
  "meta":  {},
  "data":  [
     {
      "username": "carolinabentocb",
      "profile_picture": "https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11429783_1673078532912085_1496721162_a.jpg",
      "id": "363753337",
      "full_name": "Carolina Bento"
    },
     {
      "username": "pereira3044",
      "profile_picture": "https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11351764_1662987433917180_971708049_a.jpg",
      "id": "2141448590",
      "full_name": "Alex"
    }
]
}
```

In [this link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson#JsValue-to-a-model) it is explained on how to map a json object to a model class, but how can I map the json array to a Seq/List/Array of Users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Json inception code is really great and it my preferred way to deserialize json. You will have to modify your User class to fit the instagram model API. Alternatively you could make a case class like `InstagramApiUser` or something to do the deserialization and copy to your own class later if you decide that is better for your flow. Here is the code and it works in a scala repl.

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Format}


val js = Json.parse("""{
  "pagination":  {},
  "meta":  {},
  "data":  [
     {
      "username": "carolinabentocb",
      "profile_picture": "https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11429783_1673078532912085_1496721162_a.jpg",
      "id": "363753337",
      "full_name": "Carolina Bento"
    },
     {
      "username": "pereira3044",
      "profile_picture": "https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11351764_1662987433917180_971708049_a.jpg",
      "id": "2141448590",
      "full_name": "Alex"
    }
  ]
}""")

case class User(id: String, username: String, profile_picture: String, full_name: String)
object User {
  implicit val jsonFormat: Format[User] = Json.format[User]
}

val result = (js \ "data").as[Seq[User]]
```

There are three methods to deserialize Json in the Play Json library, and `as` is the least idiomatic one in my opinion as it throws an exception if it fails to parse. You could try using `asOpt[A]` which will produce an `Option[A]` or better `validate[A]` which will produce a `JsResult[A]` and then you can log an error with the reason(s) that parsing your Json failed.

If you don't like naming your case class members to match the API names you can write the `Reads` manually like

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Reads, JsPath}
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class User(val userId: String, val username: String, val profilePhoto: String, val name: String)
object User {
  implicit val jsonReads: Reads[User] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "username").read[String] and 
    (JsPath \ "profile_picture").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "full_name").read[String]
  )(User.apply _)
}
```

And it works the same way otherwise.

Comment: That's nice! But there's no way to avoid the field names to match the json names? `profile_picture` is a bit 'ugly' for instance...

Comment: My solution was to add nicer getter methods like:

`def name: String = full_name` and `def profilePhoto: String = profile_picture`

Comment: I agree. I wouldn't want to use underscores in the names of class members in my User object either. I tend to make single use case classes for parsing out the API data and then move the data to a 'prettier' model case class. However, if you don't want to do that you can also manually write the Json `Reads`. I'll edit my answer to show an example.

Comment: how to implement this but with optional json fields?
When getting info about media, I want `JsPath \ "caption" \ "text"` but sometimes the caption is just null...

Comment: 4get, just found the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207942/how-to-handle-optional-fields-in-json-parsing-in-play-2-1

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've found is the following:

```
val users: Seq[User] = (json \ "data").as[JsArray].value.map(j => j.validate[User].get)
```

It may exist a more beautiful approach, but I will stick with this one until other answers.

Comment: I have Long type in one of the property of scala case class. but when i convert json to seq of that class it gives me "erro.expected.long"