# Take data from two different Json files to create an Seq[Object] in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have a class model like this

```scala
final case class Appointment(id: Option[String] = None,
                             service: Option[String] = None,
                             start_at: Option[String] = None,
                             end_at: Option[String] = None,
                             entity: Option[String] = None,
                             status: Option[String] = None,              
                             beneficiary: Option[String] = None,
                            )
```

I get responses from two diferent APIs that give JSONs with different structure, the first one have the same structure as my class, so to get it's data it's enough with this:

```scala
object Appointment {

    implicit val jsonFormat: OFormat[Appointment] = Json.format[Appointment]
}
```

But the second one it's different like this:

```
{
 data[
  {
    "id": 101643,
    "establishment": "some stablishment",
    "id_client": 125,
    "reservation_date": "2023-01-23",
    "date_start": "2023-01-23T05:00:00.000000Z",
    "date_end": "2023-01-23T05:00:00.000000Z",
    "service": "some service",
  }]
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249332/convert-json-array-to-seq-of-model-class-in-scala-play-framework) I found a solution when it's one way or another but I need a way to combine both methods. I can't change my class attributes and also can't do this:

```scala
object User {
  implicit val jsonReads: Reads[User] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "username").read[String] and 
    (JsPath \ "profile_picture").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "full_name").read[String]
  )(User.apply _)
}
```

because I will brake the implementation already existing.

**Note** I need `Seq[Appointment]`

# Summarizing
I need create a `Seq[Appointment]` either with the info gived to from the first API or from the second, both APIs give responsens with different structures, and the second one give a structure different to my `class Appointment` model

Comment: Creating 2 case classes and providing a method to transform one in the other is not an option?

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks, but I belive is't an option right now, I tried to simplify the problem, but is part of a bigger situation and other peopel are working over the same model and right now, creating 2 case classes may create other problems in the future

Comment: I don't have the full picture but I would think the case class used to represent data of the webservice called should not be the same as the one used for your business logic. You'd only be creating an intermediate case class your people wouldn't even know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of [`orElse`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.html#orElse(v:play.api.libs.json.Reads%5BA%5D):play.api.libs.json.Reads%5BA%5D)

It's a method on the `Reads` trait which allows you to combine multiple `Reads` in a sort of "fallback" chain. If the first one fails, it tries the second one.

Make a separate `Reads` for each JSON format you want to support, then `orElse` them together to create a single `Reads` that supports all formats.

The details of doing so will depend on how your classes are designed. I.e. do they share a common supertype? Are they completely separate, but have a conversion from one type to the other?

For example you might do

```scala
implicit val theOtherTypeReads: Reads[TheOtherAppointmentType] = /* ... */

implicit val appointmentReads: Reads[Appointment] = {
  val defaultReads = Json.reads[Appointment]
  val otherTypeReads = theOtherTypeReads.map(_.convertToAppointment)
  defaultTypeReads.orElse(otherTypeReads)
}
```

or

```scala
implicit val appointmentReads: Reads[Appointment] = {
  val subtype1Reads = Json.reads[AppointmentSubtype1]
  val subtype2Reads = Json.reads[AppointmentSubtype2]
  subtype1Reads orElse subtype2Reads
  // note, the Json.reads macro might already do this for you,
  // if `Appointment` is a sealed trait...
}
```

Comment: I think this is the solution, I have not been able to test it, As soon as I try it, I will point it out accordingly, thanks